# Floating object inside another floating object in ConTeXt

Tags: floats, subfloats, context

I need page where is text column with pictures on the left side. Inside the text column I need on the right side floating letter. Here is code:

```
\starttext
    \startfiguretext[left]{none}%
        {\externalfigure[ http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5260/5543764878_c5b27b5aed_s.jpg]
            [width=26.5mm,height=26.5mm]}%
        \framed[frame=off,width=96mm,align=flushleft]{%
            \placefigure[right,none,fit]{none}{%
                \framed[frame=off,background=letteroverlay,height=1cm]{ A}
            }%
        {\bfb Bla bla bla}%

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc lobortis
        accumsan sem vitae molestie. Mauris tincidunt elementum mi, semper aliquet
        sapien convallis sed.%
        }%
    \stopfiguretext%
\stoptext
```

Problem is, that if I use the framed for letter "A" picture disapears. How to have floated framed box inside another frame? I cannot use margin, because this should be inside two columns.

Final document should look like this picture:

[image: How document should look]

Comment: I have no idea what you want to achieve. You should improve your description or add a graphic that shows the intended result. Additionally your code doesn't compile (with latest beta).

Comment: I can compile code with:

mtx-context     | current version: 2011.05.18 18:04

Answer (score 1):

Still, I'm not sure if I got the idea what you want to do. According to your title you want one float inside another one. This doesn't make much sense. I think you don't really want several floating objects but particular features of the `\placefloat` command.

I do neither see columns in your example, nor how the example code matches the graphic you provided. However, this is a solution I can come up with:

```
% for the placeholder graphic
\useMPlibrary [dum]

\setuplayout [backspace=5cm, width=middle]

\definefloat      [innerfloat] [innerfloats]
\setupcaption     [innerfloat] [location=none]
\defineframedtext [innerfloat] [frame=off, width=1cm]

\starttext

\inmargin{%
  \externalfigure
    [placeholder]
    [width=26.5mm,height=26.5mm]
  {\bfb Bla bla bla}\par
  Some text…}

\input knuth

\startplaceinnerfloat [location={right,fit}]
  \startinnerfloat
    \bfc A
  \stopinnerfloat
\stopplaceinnerfloat

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

Since floats in columns are tricky I used the margin as a column.